# Date Quarters in 'Series' object python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

I'm trying to count the value in each date in order to count witch quarter is high frequency I try these methods not working so far... please help :) thanks.
Note: stime is 'Series' object

```
stime=df['timestamp']
#print (df['timestamp'].filter(like='08', axis=0)
#stime.filter(like='2018-07-18')
#stime.between_date('2018-01-01','2018-02-01', include_start=True, include_end=True)
#stime.month
```

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Is this what your looking for: `df.set_index('timestamp').resample('Q').size()` ?

Comment: @ChrisA  my data contain column timestamp ex:'2018-08-29'

Comment: @ChrisA I want to count how many I have in August = 8 (month) and etcetera for all months to calculate the quarters of the year

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2018-01-07', '2018-01-08', '2018-04-08',
                                  '2018-03-09', '2018-09-08', '2018-12-08',
                                  '2018-01-21', '2018-09-11', '2018-03-08',
                                  '2018-11-08', '2018-10-18', '2018-04-04']})
data.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(data.timestamp)
data['quarter'] = data.timestamp.dt.quarter
data['month'] = data.timestamp.dt.month

data.groupby(['quarter', 'month']).month.count()
```

I hope it helps. If you want count by year too, you can add `data['year'] = data.timestamp.dt.year` and `data.groupby(['quarter', 'month', 'year']).month.count()`